# What is the best way to sync two devices heartbeat on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift

I am developing an application on two iOS clients. But both two iOS clients may not able to connect to the Internet, that's make query the same network time difficult. If I send one time stamp to another via wireless or bluebooth or something else, it may have a time delay, like this:

1. Device A, get the timestamp from the Device A.
2. Device A send the information to Device B.
3. Device B mark the timestamp.
4. Device B receive the timestamp information from Device A.
5. Device B create a new timestamp, and add back the timestamp different between transferring data.

I am afraid that the create timestamp, and object creation will use some time that cannot be logged. And the application is very time critical. Is there any ways to improve that? Thanks.

Comment: Why is the application very time critical? If the problem is with the *sequencing* of distributed events, maybe a [vector clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clock) would be a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way is

1. Device A sends information to Device B (without timestamp)
2. Device B responses to Device A timestamp of reception.
3. Device A receives the timestamp of data delivery.

In this case both Device A and Device B will receive same timestamp of data sharing.